# Lookup in a map of Integer ranges in Golang

Tags: arrays, algorithm, go, hashmap, range

The problem I want to resolve can be expressed this way: I want to lookup an Integer in a hashmap of integer ranges.

```
0-4: dog,
5-8: cat,
9-18: bird,
19-21: dog,
22-22: bird,
...
```

Where:

```
lookup(3) -> dog
lookup(10) -> bird
```

However, thinking of this problem as a hashmap is probably not the right way to go.
I'm working with ~ 140,000 ranges, which belong to one of ~ 200 possible classes.

Any idea of how to do this in Golang ? Or which track to follow to reach a reasonable solution (~O(log(n) ?) ? A way to describe this problem more generically ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: If the classes are _disjunct_ and _cover_ the whole range then a range can be identified by its start (the and if the range is the start of the next range - 1). Just put the ranges into a sorted slice. Lookup is log n.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If ranges are *disjunct* (that is a concrete number can only belong to one range), you can find a range using a binary search. This is `O(log(n))` complexity.

If ranges are *contiguous*, it is also enough to "model" a range using only one number, either with its start or its end. This also applies in your case.

We can list the range boundaries in an `int` slice in ascendent order, and we can perform a binary search in this sorted slice. We  model ranges with their maximum value since the sequence of ranges is without any holes. This will give us the index of the range. We can store the names in a separate slice, and return the  name at the index we just found as the result of binary search.

*Here's the surprisingly short implementation, a **one-line function**:*

```
var ranges = []int{-1, 4, 8, 18, 21, 22}
var names = []string{"", "dog", "cat", "bird", "dog", "bird", ""}

func getName(n int) string {
    return names[sort.SearchInts(ranges, n)]
}
```

Testing it:

```
nums := []int{-1, 3, 6, 10, 20, 22, 100}
for _, n := range nums {
    if name := getName(n); name == "" {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid number: %4d\n", n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Number        : %4d, Name: %s\n", n, name)
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K0BNzVcFYu)):

```
Invalid number:   -1
Number        :    3, Name: dog
Number        :    6, Name: cat
Number        :   10, Name: bird
Number        :   20, Name: dog
Number        :   22, Name: bird
Invalid number:  100
```

Note: this solution is also used in a similar question on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site: [Classifying by age](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/classifying-by-age)

#### Handling non-contiguous ranges

If ranges would not cover every number (meaning there are "holes" between ranges), then you may easily handle that by adding the holes as "virtual" ranges, and give them the empty string `""` name (which we used for invalid ranges). That's all.

For example, let's modify your original problem to this:

```
0-4: dog,
5-8: cat,
9-15: bird,
19-21: dog,
22-22: bird,
```

As you can see, there is a "hole" between `9-15: bird` and `19-21:dog`. The range `16-17` is invalid. Here's how you can map this:

```
var ranges = []int{-1, 4, 8, 15, 18, 21, 22}
var names = []string{"", "dog", "cat", "bird", "", "dog", "bird", ""}
```

There is an empty `""` name for the range between `15` and `18`. Testing it:

```
nums := []int{15, 16, 19}
for _, n := range nums {
    if name := getName(n); name == "" {
        fmt.Printf("Invalid number: %4d\n", n)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Number        : %4d, Name: %s\n", n, name)
    }
}
```

Output (try this variant on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ucfdy3PvL1)):

```
Number        :   15, Name: bird
Invalid number:   16
Number        :   19, Name: dog
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different approach that implements the [`sort.Interface`](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) rather than using 2 slices and handles non-contiguous ranges:

```
type Range struct {
    Min, Max int
    Value    string
}
type Ranges []Range

func (r Ranges) Len() int           { return len(r) }
func (r Ranges) Less(i, j int) bool { return r[i].Min < r[j].Min }
func (r Ranges) Swap(i, j int)      { r[i], r[j] = r[j], r[i] }
func (r Ranges) Sort()              { sort.Sort(r) }
func (r Ranges) Search(v int) string {
    ln := r.Len()
    if i := sort.Search(ln, func(i int) bool { return v <= r[i].Max }); i < ln {
        if it := &r[i]; v >= it.Min && v <= it.Max {
            return it.Value
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](https://play.golang.org/p/5DNqKkNPuA)